# Shimano Alfine 11 hub axle unit assembly

Tags: shimano, internally-geared-hub, alfine

I have a bike with a Shimano Alfine 11 hub. While overhauling the hub, I accidentally took off the block on the drive side of the hub axle unit:

[image]

Now I have half a dozen parts I have no idea how to put back together. Derp.

None of the materials I found on the internet (videos, web pages, manuals, including the official overhaul manual from Shimano) mentions anything about disassembly or assembly of the axle unit, and only the entire unit is available for sale. I'm probably going to have to order a replacement, but I figured I'd ask if somebody here knows something: **how can I put this thing back together?**

Comment: This might help: https://youtu.be/qfwm_5NjAWw
I don't think he disassembles the axle unit fully though, in a different video he disassembles a Nexus - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s9BJvyp-djw - not exactly the same but at least gives a general idea of what's in there.

Comment: Have you had any results?  Clearly this is a problem encountered by others too.  Even a progress update might be useful.

Answer (score 3):

In the end, I gave up and ordered a replacement axle unit on Ebay. Quite a disappointment, but what can you do.

If you decide to order a replacement as well, be careful and make sure you check the part code. At some point, Shimano released a revised version of Alfine 11 (SG-S7001), and axle unit is one of the parts that aren't interchangeable with the old revision (SG-S700).

Here's the interchangeability table (PDF: [shimano.com](https://dassets.shimano.com/content/dam/global/cg1SHICCycling/final/ev/ev/EV-SG-S7001-11-4207A.pdf)):

[image: Interchangeability table]